# Having serious trouble trying to close old methods/activities in my app

Tags: android, layout, android-activity

I posted a detailed question here:

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4252194/need-help-closing-accessing-my-views-in-a-simple-app-included-an-img-of-my-progr

but I might have been too confusing.

Basically, I have an app that has a main menu where the user can click a button to open a camera.  The user then snaps a photo and it is displayed on a page.  The user will then click another button that detects faces.  If faces are detected, the user is sent to a final page that shows the cropped face, etc...I give the user the ability to return to the main menu or snap a new photo.

Let's say a new photo is snapped and the user does it a few more times.  Now I have multiple saved instances of old snapped photos (presented on the layout).  How do I kill the previous instance (the layout from before he decided to snap a new photo)?  So when I try to close the app it doesn't go back to the previous instance (displayed layout of said snapped photo).

Thanks for any help, I am so confused on this one thing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Either call `finish()` on each activity after firing the intent for the next activity (assuming you never want to let the user go backwards), or use [Intent task flags](http://developer.android.com/guide/practices/ui_guidelines/activity_task_design.html) when launching your take-a-new-photo or main-menu Intent. Here,  FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP passed to your main menu/snap-new-photo intent will clear out the tasks in the middle so the user can't back into them.

Comment: I keep getting back to those solutions, but I don't quite know how to use them.  I fire off my intent's in some of my button clicks, while others I just call methods (my button clicks are in a different OnClickListener method)...where do I place the finish(); or the FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP calls in this case?

Comment: Just put them wherever you're calling startActivity. Example: flags (added when relaunching the main menu): `startActivity(new Intent(activity, MainMenuActivity.class).setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP));` and for `finish()` (add when starting a followup activity to prevent returning to the current one): `startActivity(new Intent(somesubactivity)); finish();`

Comment: Thank you!  Will I not be able to setFlags on methods that are void?

Comment: Not sure what you mean by that -- you're calling `setFlags` on the new `Intent` object (which in turn returns the Intent object too), and calling `startActivity` on that whole thing. There's no void in there. Maybe you were misparsing those parentheses and thought I was calling setFlags on the return of `startActivity`?